# Visual Source Safe New files check in

Tags: visual-studio, visual-sourcesafe

I have asp files on server and i created a working folder and checked out code. I then created new files in working folder and did checkin but they new files are not copied.

Does VSS do not copy new files or is there a way i can check in those files to VSS database.

Comment: Not an answer, but you really should look into changing your source control to something better than VSS.

Comment: yes but now i need to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add them to the location you want to check them in before you can commit them.  You will have to use the VSS tool to do this.

Comment: can you direct me to link or how can i do that using VSS

Comment: so stupid of me to ask that but i already figured it out thanks btw

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually add the new files to VSS.